# Ошибка при определении местонахождения

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вот возникла следующая ошибка сразу после запуска приложения:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bogdan.gps_location, PID: 29305
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bogdan.gps_location/com.example.bogdan.gps_location.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
        at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:614)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:899)
        at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:472)
        at com.example.bogdan.gps_location.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773) 
Application terminated.
```

MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private static final String TAG= MainActivity.class.getName();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LocationManager lm =
                (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this); //здесь ошибка
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Широта="+location.getLatitude());
            Log.d(TAG, "Долгота="+location.getLongitude());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bogdan.gps_location">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с API 23 (вроде бы) мало прописать разрешения в манифесте, надо запросить их у пользователя (используя `requestPermissions()`), да ещё и во время выполнения всегда проверять наличие (потому что пользователь как дал, так и забрал).

Как это сделать написано в [этом официальном документе](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: И да я использую api 21

Comment: "Я использую" - где именно?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: И как это применить в коде

Comment: По ссылке все написано.